# node-sqlite3 failed to bind parameters in run method

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I tried to execute next code(simplified):

```
var placeholders = {
    $id: 1,
    $value: 'some value',
};

var sql = "INSERT INTO table(id,value) VALUES($id, $value)";
var st = db.prepare(sql);

st.run(sql, placeholders, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        //callback(false);
    }else{
        console.log(this);
        //callback(true);
    }
});
```

Placeholders were replaced with null in result query.

```
{ [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: NOT NULL constraint failed: table.value] errno: 19,
 code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT' }
```

What am I doing wrong?

node 0.10.24
 sqlite3 2.2.0
 windows 8 32-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Statement#run([param, ...], [callback])**

You cannot pass the sql statement as its param in run method. The column constraint 'NOT NULL' cannot be satisfied because your params are parsed in a wrong way.

```
var placeholders = {
    $id: 1,
    $value: 'some value'
};

var sql = "INSERT INTO test (id,value) VALUES($id, $value)";
var st = db.prepare(sql);

st.run(placeholders, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        //callback(false);
    } else {
        console.log(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. You show me my mistake, but problem was deeper. Object placeholders has one placeholder, that not use in run method. Example:

`var placeholders = {
    $id: 1,
    $value2: 'some unused value',
    $value: 'some value'
};
`
And as result I give next error:

{ [Error: SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column index out of range] errno: 25, code: 'SQL
ITE_RANGE' }

I drop unused property and all works.